# sum function incorrect values and list of not paid yet this month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my first table, where it contains buying information about clients. So if a client buy two objects (TV and Phone), 2 rows are added as following:

**Row 1:**

> ID = 12321, client_name = 'X', total_debts = 560, sale_type = 'TV LG 40'' ', date =..., time =...

**Row 2:**

> ID = 34564, client_name = 'X', total_debts = 700, sale_type = 'iPhone', date =..., time =...

Those are entered in this table called **client_debts**

Now I have, a second table where it control the paying of each customer. So when Mr. X, came and pays from his total 1260$, just 200$ this month, it will be added to **client_details** like the following:

> id = 8642234, client_id = 34564, client_name = 'X', payment = 200, date_now =..., time_now=...

I don't care on which item he pays his installment, so I added to client_id, the last buying id.

What I want to make is a comparison between total debts of each client, and his total payments. So i tried each query alone:

```
SELECT client_name, sum(total_debts) FROM alamir_store.client_debts GROUP BY client_name;
```

And I got this result:

[image]

The second query was:

```
SELECT client_name, sum(payment) FROM client_details GROUP BY client_name;
```

And the result is:

[image]

What I really want is to combine those 2 tables together, so I can see how much we still have from **each** client, **and we want to see if he pays this month on any of his object or not** to put him on our **NOT PAID LIST**

I have tried this query but didn't get me the logic result:

```
SELECT t1.client_name, sum(total_debts), sum(payment)  FROM
client_debts t1 INNER JOIN client_details t2  GROUP BY t1.client_name;
```

The result is:

[image]

**Any help is appreciated, to correct this error and how to make a NOT PAID YET THIS MONTH LIST**

Comment: Why do you join if all you need is in one table?

Comment: I am trying, I am quite new to MySQL. And those are 2 tables that I am working with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the query below, but it is advisable you use the client ID for the join:

```
select td1.client_name,td1.TotalDebt,td2.TotalPayment from (SELECT client_name, sum(total_debts) as TotalDebt FROM client_debts GROUP BY client_name) as td1
inner JOIN
(SELECT client_name, sum(payment) as TotalPayment FROM client_details GROUP BY client_name) as td2
on td1.client_name=td2.client_name
```

Comment: can you explain this query to me ?

Comment: what the query is doing is to find the sum separately from each table and then do a join of those tables. where you see "as td1" is making the query as a new table named td1 and the other as td2 then you can join these new tables based on thier columns using the client name as the join condition..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check the condition for matching the same client in both the tables. Use the below query

```
SELECT t1.client_name, sum(total_debts), sum(payment) FROM 
client_debts t1 INNER JOIN client_details t2 
ON t1.ID=t2.client_id GROUP BY t1.client_name;
```

Comment: nope, it gives me on sum(total_debts) the double of each value, so if someone had 1660$ as total, it is showing me as 3320$

Comment: users that have only one item, display their value correctly, but when a user has multiple purchased items, it double the total debts, so we still in the same error

Comment: This query works fine for a Normalized table. If you want to refine the query, please create a sql fiddle.

Comment: how can I normalize my tables ?

Comment: Even though Normalization is big thing, You can quickly learn it here and do it yourself. [http://searchbusinessintelligence.techtarget.in/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps]